# Visualise significant differences in a contingency table?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, scipy

I'm working with pandas and scipy, and I would like to find a quick way to visualise unusual values in a contingency table.

Say this is my contingency table:

```
                  wolves   lions   tigers   chickens    total
ate_zebra         14112    13891   12978    54          41035
ignored_zebra     6403     6377    6109     2637        21526
total             20515    20268   19087    2691        62561
```

It looks as though chickens are (mostly) vegetarian, unlike the other animals.

If I run a chi-squared test, it tells me that the chi-squared value is significant and the expected values are:

```
wolves      lions       tigers      chickens    total
13456.19515 13294.18296 12519.54165 1765.080242 41035
7058.804846 6973.817043 6567.458353 925.9197583 21526
20515       20268       19087       2691        62561
```

But what I'd really like is some way to quickly, visually identify the most significant differences from the expected values, say something like this:

[image: contingency table with most significant deviations from expected values highlighted]

Excel would be good enough, but something Python-based would would be ideal :) Or do I need to write my own algorithm to do this?

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: I may hint towards computing and presenting _standardized_ or _adjusted_ Pearson residuals.

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks! That does look like the right approach.

Comment: Another (somewhat related) possibility is contribution to chi-square, but I generally prefer standardized Pearson residuals.

Comment: heatmaps will be good.